# How to specify privacy settings( public , friends or only me) for wall post using Facebook SDK 4 in Android

Tags: android, facebook

Is there any method to specify the privacy setting for wall post using facebook SDK 4? SessionDefaultAudience class was used in previous version of facebook SDK. But what to do for latest facebook SDK?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/DefaultAudience/

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got a solution for wall post using facebook SDK 4 with privacy:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

//use this line for all friends
jsonObject.put("value", "ALL_FRIENDS"); 
//or use this line for public
jsonObject.put("value", "EVERYONE");
//or use below 3 line for custom
jsonObject.put("value", "CUSTOM");
jsonObject.put("friends", "SOME_FRIENDS");
jsonObject.put("allow", theFriendsListIdForFamily);

Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("privacy", jsonObject.toString());
```